# What's the best way to use CSV source data in a list component?

Tags: aem

Disclaimer: I am not an AEM developer, I'm filling in on a project, so forgive me if I am missing the obvious.

I have a page template that will contain a component that will show a list of locations, this template will be used for many city pages.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to get the content into the JCR or read it using a script from a CSV file.

Are there any out-of-the box or open source components out there that can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to accomplish your task. The easy part should be rendering the information. You would usually implement a `Sling model` or a class extending `WCMUse`, access the repository via the Sling API and render the resources via `Adobe HTL`. The resources being rendered have to be selected of course: write a Servlet which provides an interface to the resources and use an adequate form element in the component's dialog.

The hard part consists of two parts:

1. Perhaps just upload the file, process the data and by using the Sling API for resource creation, you can write the data into the repo. You could also utilise the DAM for such tasks and implement a workflow.
2. Depending on the amount of data, you might want to save the data as JSON string as property of a node.

I hoped that helped a bit.

Answer (score 1):

"Are there any out-of-the box or open source components out there that can accomplish this?"

Simple answer: NO

While there are several libraries that can help you parse CSV files, storing it in JCR depends completely on your project. The structure can be arbitrary or (in a brute force way) you can just store the CSV file as data in your node but that may not be useful.

Depending on how you plan to use the data, it may be useful and optimal to save it in a relevant hierarchy for your project.